# Select-Object - Keep default columns but add one

Tags: powershell

I can use Select-Object to choose which columns to show and even add calculated columns. An example:

```
gci | select *, @{n='LAS'; e={(Get-Date)-$_.LastAccessTime}}
```

I want add a calculated column but keep the defaut ones. Without the * wildcard I only get my calculated property. With it I get everything. The only workaround I've got to work is to manually list the default property names. Any ideas?

Comment: You may have to use one of the `Format-*` cmdlets and add the new calculated property that way instead. Does `Format-Table -Property *, @{n='LAS'; e={(Get-Date)-$_.LastAccessTime}} -AutoSize` behave differently?

Comment: @Abraham Zinala : No, it's the same result. In addition it removes the option of using my calculated property elsewhere in the pipeline.

Comment: Short answer is, use the workaround.

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that that you actually states to display **all** properties ('*').

So to add to only the standard properties, you first need to get the standard properties.

```
[string[]]$StdProperties = (Get-ChildItem).PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet[1].ReferencedPropertyNames
```

We don't actually want to change the standard property of the objects returned

```
Get-Childitem | select Name | Get-Member| group TypeName | select Name

Name
----
Selected.System.IO.DirectoryInfo
Selected.System.IO.FileInfo
```

So we just need to expand on that extracted string array with the new property to use.

```
$StdProperties += 'LAS'
```

And finally, to put it to use...

```
Get-ChildItem | select *, @{n='LAS'; e={(Get-Date) - $_.LastAccessTime}} | 
select $StdProperties
```

Comment: For more reference about Default Properties, see [Define default properties for custom objects](https://poshoholic.com/2008/07/05/essential-powershell-define-default-properties-for-custom-objects/)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, building on [Abrahams comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68706871/select-object-keep-default-columns-but-add-one#comment121422955_68706871), you could do something weird like this:

```
# get the default properties used on Format-Table
$defaultProps = (((Get-ChildItem | Format-Table | Out-String) -split '\r?\n' | 
                    Where-Object { $_ -match '^\w.*' }) | 
                    Select-Object -First 1) -split '\s+' -ne ''

# now execute the command
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object *, @{n='LAS'; e={(Get-Date)-$_.LastAccessTime}} | 
    Select-Object ($defaultProps + 'LAS') | Format-Table -AutoSize
```